# Why I see sentences reapeating the same semantics twice with different words

Tags: grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context, controversial

Is ironic that feature and characteristic have the same meaning and the dictionary repeated twice, this is purely superfluous.

Why does this happen?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`3. regard a quality or feature as characteristic of or possessed by (someone or something)`

In that example, "feature" is a noun, and "characteristic" is an adjective, so they don't have the same meaning. Not all features are characteristic. For example, if a car has a pinstripe, that is a feature. If not all examples of that car have the same feature, it is not characteristic of them.

Comment: Is there a repetition?  'quality' and 'feature' are semantically dissimilar. Similarly, 'characteristic of' and 'possessed by' are not similar.

Comment: I don't see a repetition.